# The functions after backgroundworkers execute before the tasks completed

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to the Windows Form in Visual Studio 2017.
I am trying to create a simple application which start counting from 1 to 100 when clicking on the button, and then create a popup window once the process is done. My button click function looks like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        worker1.RunWorkerAsync(value);
        Open_Prompt(); //pop-up window
    }
```

However, I realized that the function Open_prompt executes before previous function finishes.
How should I modify the code so that the pop-up window will only appear after the counting is completed?
Thank you.

Comment: Counting to 100 does not require a backgrounder worker, it takes well less than a microsecond.  If it needs to be visible to the user then use a Timer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use async method

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button1.Enabled = false;
     await DoWorkAsync(e);
     MessageBox.Show("Done!");
     button1.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task DoWorkAsync(object value)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
       //Some work
    });
}
```

However you can do this with background worker as below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //i do something
        };
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            button1.Enabled = true;
        };

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the on completed eventing handler. It will wait until the caller is complete.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += eventHandler;
            worker1.RunWorkerAsync(1);


        }

        private void eventHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate ()
            {
                Open_Prompt();
            };

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
            else
                methodInvokerDelegate();
        }
```

Comment: `RunWorkerCompleted` runs on the UI thread once the `DoWork` process has completed so the majority of the code is redundant. You could just call `Open_Prompt();`. Also, you shouldn't be assigning the eventhandler in the button click unless you're also creating `worker1` at that point. If `worker1` is assigned an event handler each time `button1` is clicked it'll cause the eventHandler event to be fired the number of times that `button1` has been clicked.